Looking for a short story about a man who dies but his ghost lives on for eons
I read a story in an anthology several years ago about a man who dies and then regains consciousness as a ghost. He wanders around for a bit, but then gets lonely. He decides to wait until his ex-wife dies so he can have some company, but she dies and immediately, out of spite, ascends.
The man continues to wander the earth for years until no one speaks  his original language, people have evolved, continents have sunk/turned to deserts, and eventually humans leave the planet. I can't remember how the story ends or if he ever ascends, but would love to find the title of the story or the title of the anthology.

Reminds me of the plotline of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Ghost_Story

Could possibly be "The Great Divorce" by C.S. Lewis. Has a few of the same plot points, he dies, wanders for a bit, he meets a girl who ascends to heaven. Even if it's not what your looking for, very much recommended.

This doesn't seem a very good match, aside from the man being a ghostly presence

Not the story I was looking for, but it sounds interesting - I'll have to check it out. Thanks!
